# jQuery hasClass() not working in IE 11 , but works in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I have the below piece of code which works perfectly in Chrome and Firefox , but in IE 10 and 11 , it is not working.

Also when I open the Developer Tools in IE ,it works correctly.

Can anyone help out?

```
$("body" ).on( "click", ".js-save-request-meta", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var el = $(this);
    var meta_value = el.data('meta-value') || $('input[name="meta_value"]').val();
     if(el.hasClass('aspect-is-selected')){
        $.post( "../ajax/delete_Request_Meta.php", {meta_value:meta_value,request_id:RequestData.request_id} )
        .done(function( data ) {
            showMessage( data );                       
         });

    }else{

        $.post( "../ajax/save_Request_Meta.php", {meta_value:meta_value,request_id:<?=$request['request_id']?> } )

         .done(function( data ) {
            showMessage( data );              
                }      
           });     
});
```

Comment: i dont think hasClass should have any problem in IE11

Comment: `var meta_value = el.data('meta-value') || $('input[name="meta_value"]').val();`    can you explain this

Comment: @ArunPJohny : JQuery version is 2.1.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is caused due to caching problem. This can be rectified by changing the settings in the browser to clear cache and refresh from server. But IE 11 still has issue with the refreshing of cache.

But the code works fine in IE 10. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try adding missing function

```
var isFunc = $.isFunction($.fn.lettering);

if (!isFunc){
  jQuery.fn.yourfunctionname = function() {
    return new RegExp(' ' + className + ' ').test(' ' + this[0].className + ' ');
  };
}
```